# Does the SIP still protect against other operating systems?

Tags: macos, big-sur, sip

System Integrity Protection from Apple protects very important parts of the system and is, in my opinion, the main reason a Mac is so secure.

That's why I ask myself the question whenever I boot Linux or Windows, for example, on a different volume. Can Windows, for example, then change something in the area of e.g. / system or does the system integrity protection also protect there?

The same question also with disk mode. Is the Mac protected by the SIP if it is used as a hard drive by another Mac?

Comment: SIP is a kernel feature that disallows non-apple software access to some important parts of the system. In doing that it is not so special that it makes a Mac more secure than other platforms. Windows has its own mechanism called the "Trusted Installer" doing almost the same. Both of them are designed to protect your system from being rendered unusable by 3rd party software. They won't protect your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, System Integrity Protection is not active when you are running other operating systems or when you mount the hard drive in another computer.

There are other protection mechanisms (such as Secure Boot and T2 disk encryption) on modern Macs that protect your system from booting "malicious" (i.e. infected) operating systems, and from the disk being simply mounted on a different computer.